# What is hot key to toggle appearance/disappearance of audio volume display in T60?

Tags: windows-xp, audio, thinkpad, hotkeys

Somehow I pressed a key combination on my Lenovo T60, XP and the large volume indicator sprang into my view in the lower center of the screen and now remains there instead of hiding except when used.

I searched "T60" hotkeys, and the Lenovo site with many types of key words without success. I cannot find the map of hotkeys.

Can anyone tell me how to hide it again?

EDIT:
Shortly after posting this request, my computer suddenly crashed, completely off, no screen, nothing. I had Outlook, a phone app and Chrom up with 20?? tabs open.

I then did a hard boot (of course) and the computer sputtered back to life. The on-screen volume indicator was not up. I tested it and it works properly again.

I will not close this as it may be useful, but I have no objection to it being closed. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's some bug.

It should be hidden after custimizeable delay that can be set in display settings.

[image]

I'm using ThinkPads for more than 10 years (since t40) never seen keyboard shortcut like this (to turn off OSD fade out).

Software responsible for OSD sometimes stuck and volume bar is not fading out.

You can kill process responsible for that (it's probably TPONSCR.exe process) and start it again (TPONSCR.exe it is somewhere in Lenovo/IBM/ThinkPad/ThinkVantage directory in Program Files).

You can also try to turn on Full Screen Magnifier (Fn+Space) and turn it off (Fn+Space). Maybe it will refresh screen and your volume bar will disappear.

You can also just logout and login again or restart to fix this.

If your OSD "stucks" frequently:

- try to install new or just diffrent version
- run Windows Update or update Microsoft Visual C++ libraries manually

  (current version is here: [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86) at microsoft.com](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555))

Comment: +1. See my edit. Thanks for "on screen display" pointer.